# Showing images properly in a listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I have a listview show a custom row layout showing a Textview and 2 EditTexts.
I am showing image in textview background with text over it.
Within the getView method ,i load the images asynchronously and show in the listview .
Does the listview not call the getview method for the rows that are not visible .

When i scroll the textview contains different image and gets the actual image when it becomes somewhat visible .why this behaviour is showing.kindly update as i am not getting it.

```
 public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            View v=arg1;

        EditText t1,t2;

            final TextView tv;
                       if (arg1 == null) 
               {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                   LayoutInflater lf=(LayoutInflater)conn.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                   v=lf.inflate(R.layout.layitem,arg2,false);

               }

                   tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,width/2); // setting width to same as that of mobile screen
                   ll.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);

                    tv.setLayoutParams(ll);
                   // tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);


                    t1=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    t2=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    // here count is actual no of rows that have image loaded from server rest will have default background    



               if(arg0<count)
               {
   Bitmap object=loadimage(iurl[arg0]);
          tv.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(conn.getResources(),object));


              tv.setText(texts[arg0]);
              t1.setText(prays[arg0]);
             }
             else
             {
              tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wish);
              tv.setText("");
              t1.setText("0");
             }






               return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` will call getView when they are visible or will be visible. And also in `getView` the passed argument `convertView` is actually cached view (or `null`). It may be one of you'r previously created views, so it may contain some old image that is currently not visible.

Comment: is the cached view be any of them means view for any position. how can we correct it so that the transition of change of image does not show.kindly update

Comment: You can set a dummy image in your ImageView in your getView() method. Your async image will then replace this when ready.

Comment: Thanks @Kuffs .but where should i actually replace it with async image .in the adapter .can you suggest modifications to this code.

Comment: the image is loading properly from cache but still the transition of image is showing

Comment: Cant see where your imageview is in the code you have posted but basically as soon as you have either inflated a new view or are reusing an old view, get your ImageView and set a dummy image into it.